# How to get label size from Zebra label printer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, printing, zpl

I have an MVC web application, where I need to print various labels on Zebra GK420t label printers using the ZPL-language. We have several printers in different rooms and some printers use labels in portrait orientation while others use labels in landscape orientation.

Does anyone happen to know, if there is a way to read the dimensions of the currently loaded labels from a given printer to my c#-app? Then the app can adjust the printing layout according to the different label sizes.

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't this be a Javascript question? And I would be surprised if the answer isn't "no" for that. Or does the ASP.NET application provide access to the printers (i.e. the server has the printers, and people print to those printers via your server)?

Comment: Maybe it should (I am fairly new to programming still)... At the moment I have made a small printing helper app that is running locally on windows login. It then gets the user's printing jobs from the web-server through a WebAPI. So I assume that this helper app could get the info from the connected printer (if it at all is possible)?

Comment: Yeah, the helper app would need to feed that information back. It's been a long time since I played with Zebra printers, but I think you need to load the current paper size.

Comment: OK, thanks. I am not sure how to do that. But maybe something in the System.Drawing.Printing-namespace will work, or are you having any specific points of direction you could pass? Otherwise thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to know what size of label you are printing before sending the print job.  You might want to look at the [ZPL Manual](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) specifically at the SGD commands.  You can query the printer for the Label Length using:

```
! U1 getvar "zpl.label_length"
```

However, I think you could get an erroneous value if the label length had been set to an incorrect value programmatically. I don't believe there is a corresponding width command.

This assumes that the printer is on the same network as either your client or web server, depending on how you decide to query the printer.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was looking for something like this. I will try to make it work and report back. Thanks.

Comment: @Nielsen Wondering, the suggested answer did help you in any way? The SGD commands were helpful?

Comment: @Coder Absolute, sorry for my late response! I didn't find out how to read the exact label size "on the fly" from the printer, so I ended up reading the label size that you can type in  the Windows Printer settings.  I then read those values from: PrintDialog in c#. It works in my setting, but if you haven't typed in the correct label size manually through the Windows Printer settings, it won't work. So only the second best solution.

Answer (score -1):

There is another way if your on network zebra printers. Each printer hosts its own config web page, which you can read once you know the IP address. Then this bit of python will get the label length the printer has detected from the label.  But you can see what it's doing, basically a bit of crude screen scraping and you can get the label length. This works with our Zebra ZD421 models.

```
import requests
try:
    url = 'http://'+ip+'/config.html'
    print('going to access config page for ', url)
    headers = {}
    newdata = {}
    response = requests.get(url, data=newdata, headers=headers)
    # Find the position of the words 'LABEL LENGTH'
    pos = response.text.find('LABEL LENGTH')
    # get whatever text is 20 characters before that position, 
    # grab 6 characters of that, strip off any spaces and convert
    # it to an integer. Thats your length.
    lab_len = int(response.text[pos-20: pos-14].strip())
    print('label length:', lab_len, type(lab_len))
  
except Exception as e:
    print('print_zebra_label Exception accessing config ',e)
    print('url attempted', url)
    return False
```